# Wrong URL for Firebase database in AndroidStudio

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to access my DB in firebase to read and write, but somehow the url that Android Studio uses to do it it's wrong. When I copy&paste this URL (https://xxxx-rtdb.firebaseio.com/) Google says:

> Database lives in a different region. Please change your database URL to https://xxxx-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app

(See that both URLs have the name of my proyect)
Then it recognices that I'm looking for a certain DB but why AndroidStudio sets this URL?

Here is my simply code to try this conection:

```
package com.truequeapp;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import static android.content.ContentValues.TAG;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 Button btn;
 EditText txt;
 FirebaseDatabase mDataBase;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        txt = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        btn = findViewById(R.id.button);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                crearUser();
            }
        });

    }

    private void crearUser() {
        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        System.out.println("Acceso a BD");
        DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference().child("nombre");

        myRef.setValue("Nicolas");
        myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                // This method is called once with the initial value and again
                // whenever data at this location is updated.
                String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                System.out.println("value = " + value);
                Log.d(TAG, "Value is: " + value);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                // Failed to read value
                System.out.println("failed to read value");
                Log.w(TAG, "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
            }
        });
        DatabaseReference mDatabase = database.getReference();
        mDatabase.child("usuarios").push().child("nombre").setValue("Nicolas");

    }
}
```

Comment: Consider redacting/removing your project-id from the database URL and the image you shared. It's considered PII.

Comment: could you explain this deeply please? What is PII?

Comment: PII or Personally Identifiable Information, is information that, just by looking at it, may identify a person, a corporation or other entity (your project, in this case).

Consider that, with your project-id, or the explicit Database URL here, anyone can try to read your database. This could lead into either hitting a quota (if your project is under the free plan) or a huge bill (if your project is under the Blaze plan).

In general, just try to avoid publishing this kind of information.

Comment: Thank you. I should blur that info, right?

Comment: Yes, blurring it works great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like your Realtime Database instance is in the `europe-west1` region.

As per [this note](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start#write_to_your_database) in the documentation, *"to get a reference to a database other than a `us-central1` default database, you must pass the database URL to `getInstance()`"*

Try explicitly using:

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(https://<databaseName><region>.firebasedatabase.app);
```